# Finding what application is running on port 80 and blocking my Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, port-80

I'm trying to run an Apache server on my windows machine, however, I have to run it on a different port, I'd like to run it on port 80, that way it's on my localhost.  When I type localhost into my browser address bar, I'm sent to the IIS server home page.  I have an IIS server installed that I've been unable to delete, so I simply stopped and disable the service in services.msc, but it seems to still be running.  How do I find and stop the unwanted services running on port 80 and how do I permanently delete the IIS server from my machine?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions of Windows (Win2003 and later), you can use:

```
netstat -b -o
```

On older versions of Windows (XP and earlier), I'd recommend using fport:

http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/fport.aspx

Either one will show you the process ID and filename.  The process ID should be enough to kill the process; the filename should help you track down the offending process.  You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) if you also need the pathname based on the process ID.